# Resolving Struct Type Issue on Left Join with AWS Athena View Table in AWS Glue PySpark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

In the AWS Glue PySpark environment, I am encountering an issue where, upon performing a left join on an AWS Athena View Table with a specific condition, the expected Long type results are instead returned as a Struct type '{}'. Below is the query structure of the View table that seems to be causing the problem:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Seoul'), '%x-%v') as origin_dd,
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('day', -7, DATE(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Seoul')), '%x-%v') as dd, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(uu)) as s_certified_profile
```

This dd column is left joined with another table, and it is used to represent the week number based on today's date, going back to the previous week. The issue arises when executing the view table individually it returns the correct results, but when processing the data with the following PySpark script, the unexpected behavior occurs:

```py
indicator_df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql=f"SELECT * FROM mart__week_sub WHERE week_num = '{formatted}'",
                                        database="service_bi")
....
new_df = pd.merge(new_df, indicator_df, how='left', on='week_num')
....
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(new_df)
sparkDF.printSchema()
sparkDF.show()
sparkDF.write.mode("append").format("parquet").save(kwargs["service_indicator_save_dir"])
```

Upon inspecting the schema with printSchema(), the counted information appears as a Struct type instead of Long. What approach should I take to resolve this issue? Are there any particular considerations or best practices recommended in this situation?

I would like the column to be of Long type, not Struct type, and to not return '{}'.

Comment: can you please add sample data for `indicator_df ` and  `new_df`?

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for the helping hand. I checked step by step using print(). new_df has values where week_num is represented as '2024-05'. However, indicator_df shows up as 'Empty DataFrame'... If it's empty, does it enter as struct?